# Delete object managed by shared_ptr when only one reference left

Tags: c++

I have `std::map<const char*, std::shared_ptr<Resource, ResourceDeleter>>`, which acts like a ResourceDatabase. The item into `std::map` is inserted when someone requests Resource that isn't already in the `std::map` (otherwise it will be served from the `std::map`). Similarly, when the Resource is not used anymore, it should be removed. In `ResourceDeleter`, i will remove the record from the `std::map`. The problem is that `ResourceDeleter` is never called, because there is still one `std::shared_ptr` in the `std::map`. When the item is inserted into `std::map`, there will be always 2 `std::shared_ptr` - one for the code that needs the Resource and one in the `std::map`. When the first `std::shared_ptr` is deleted, i need to remove Resource from the `std::map`.

Comment: You should look into std::weak_ptr

http://stackoverflow.com/q/12030650/1922748

Comment: When you have a parent - child relation, never store the parent pointer in the child as a shared pointer (If you do, the dependency becomes circular). Have only one shared pointer to the child in parent. (You might use a raw or weak pointer in the child)

Comment: Maybe OT but be very careful with `const char *` as key: pointer comparison will be used for the keys, which means that `the_map["abc"]` at one point might be a different entry to `the_map["abc"]` at another point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a [std::weak_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) in your std::map.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct A {
  std::string hello() { return "hello"; }
  ~A() { std::cout << "Destructor ~A() called" << std::endl; }
};

void use(std::weak_ptr<A> const& wp)
{
  if (auto spt = wp.lock())
  {
    std::cout << "Accessing object... " << spt->hello() << "\n";
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "use(): object was deleted\n";
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::weak_ptr<A> wp;
  {
    std::shared_ptr<A> sp = std::make_shared<A>();
    wp = sp;
    use(wp);
    std::cout << "Destructing sp" << std::endl;
  }
  use(wp);
  std::cout << "Destructing wp" << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

> Accessing object... hello
>   Destructing sp
>   Destructor ~A() called
>   use(): object was deleted
>   Destructing wp

Comment: This also solves the following problem: what if you also want, eg. a `std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Resource, ResourceDeleter>>`. Now you can't rely on the reference count to figure out if the object should be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the problem, the goal is that when the last shared pointer to a Resource is deleted, the Resource should be removed from the ResourceMap and then deleted. As you say, that can't work if a shared pointer to the Resource is kept in the ResourceMap, because the shared pointer in the map will always be the last shared pointer to the Resource.

So there are two simple solutions. One is to keep in the Map a weak pointer (`std::weak_ptr`) to the Resource. The other, possibly simpler solution, is to keep *the Resource itself* in the ResourceMap. In both cases, you need to wrap the `std::map` (or `std::unordered_map`) because you need to return a shared pointer to the Resource, which is not the `mapped_type` of the associative container.

The Resource can be constructed directly into the `map` using `map::emplace`.

Actually implementing ResourceDeleter is not trivial, since in order to do the deletion, you need to have access to both the map and the key (or an iterator to the value). A pointer to the value (which is what is in the shared_ptr) is clearly not sufficient.

To cut down on the size of the shared_ptr, I'd consider making the object of the shared_pointer an iterator or a pointer to the `std::pair<const key_type, mapped_type>`. Then you would need a wrapper around the smart pointer so that the `*` operator would end up being implemented as `p->second` rather than `*p`.

Comment: What happens if the weak_ptr in the map is accessed after the shared_ptr has been freed?

Comment: @MattMcNabb: If the resource deleter removes the entry from the map, that's not possible. But in general, a weak_ptr to an object whose last shared_ptr has been deleted is effectively a NULL pointer.