# Circular buffer with smart_ptr and weak_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11

I can't find a complete example that shows how to eliminating strong circular references between `shared_ptr`.

Problem is how to use a `weak_ptr` to "close" the chain of generic elements and to access the "next" element with the `weak_ptr`.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

For example, suppose to have `Element e1, e2, e3;` with pointer inside to the next element. 
In C we do

```
e1->Next = e2;
e2->Next = e3;
e3->Next = e1;
```

...and we could do `e1->Next->Next->Next->Next->Next` etc.

In C++ with `shared_ptr` we cannot do the last `->Next = e1` because of circular references and destructor will not release all the `Element`.

We need a `weak_ptr` : but what strategy to have the same result?

Comment: `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` are normally only used when the pointer *own* the underlying storage. In the case of a circular buffer, you typically have a head and tail pointer, but neither normally owns the underlying storage. For non-owning pointers like this, you raw pointers are normally fine.

Comment: need more information. can you rephrase the question, with compilable code showing what you have tried?

Comment: Also, what does this have to do with "circular buffers"? Circular *references* aren't the same thing

Comment: I think this was always a non-answerr to the problem of circular reference that somehow gained traction as an idea with `C++11`. The reference here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr still says that a weak pointer is used to break circular references but it does not provide an example of how this would be done.

Comment: While a circular buffer is a chain of circular references, and hence a problem, it isn't just any chain of circular references: it is a circularly symmetric one.  Without a symmetry break, no type-based solution can solve the issue (there is no "distinguished spot" to stick the weak pointer).  You'll have to actually describe your entire problem (not just your attempted solution) to get a solution here.

Comment: "In C we do `e1->setNext(e2);`" - That's not C.

Comment: @AmiTavory why not? `Element` can be a struct with a pointer to the next element.

Comment: @MarcoSanfilippo C doesn't have methods, only free functions.

Comment: @Galik "_weak pointer is used to break circular references_" is pure horrible non design. Like throwing a toolbox at a screw and hoping the screw will do something.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Ok I found the solution.**

When I need to access from the **last** to the **first** element of the chain (object, struct or typedef_data) simply use the **weak_prt** with `lock()` (maybe with `expired()` to check if poiter still exists...)

Example:

```
 std::weak_ptr<int> gw;

void f()
{
    if (auto spt = gw.lock()) { // Has to be copied into a shared_ptr before usage
    std::cout << *spt << "\n";
}
else {
        std::cout << "gw is expired\n";
    }
}

int main() {

{ //into the scope
    auto sp = std::make_shared<int>(42);
    gw = sp;

    f();
}
 // out of the scope
f();
}
```

So, output will be:

```
42
gw is expired
```

`expired()` is not used in this example but should be used before `lock()` and the return value of `lock()` **MUST BE** always checked.

Answer (score -2):

Probably this discussion can be useful: [When is std::weak_ptr useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030650/when-is-stdweak-ptr-useful).
In particular, the third answer is what you are searching for.

The example above is about a tree where each node has shared_ptr to its children and a weak_ptr to its parent. If instead you want to make a sort of circular buffer through a concatenated list of nodes, then you have to make a normal list using strong references, then you close the loop adding a weak_ptr from the last node to the first. When, iterating over the list, you reach the weak_ptr and you want to go ahead, you can get a shared_ptr calling the lock method on the weak_ptr; note that lock doesn't destroy the weak_ptr.

Another way to get a shared_ptr from a weak_ptr is to construct a shared_ptr passing to the constructor the weak_ptr. The outcome is the same in case of success, while its much different if the weak_ptr is expired (lock return an empty shared_ptr, while the constructor throws and exception).

Comment: "*The example above is about a tree where each node has shared_ptr to its children and a weak_ptr to its parent.*" Why should it use a `weak_ptr` to its parent instead of a regular, non-owning pointer? Children don't own their parents in any way. Children rely on the existence of their parents, and child nodes should be destroyed *before* their parent nodes. So why should they hold a `weak_ptr`?

Comment: The tree in the example is a particular type of tree that you want to navigate both top down and bottom up. The weak_ptr are used, instead of shared_ptr, because doing like this you can exploit the RAII tecnique, so that you can properly destroy all the tree by simply destroing the root. If you use shared_ptr, when you try to destroy the root, this will fail because off circular references. This is particularly important when an exception occurs and you exit the scope where the tree is defined before you can gracefully destroy it. P.S.: I'm not native English speaker, sorry for errors.

Comment: "*The weak_ptr are used, instead of shared_ptr*" I didn't say to use a `shared_ptr`; I said to use a "regular, *non-owning* pointer". That is, parents own their children; the children have *no ownership* of their parents.

Comment: @DavideVisentin yes, that's what he means