# std::shared_ptr vs std::weak_ptr in terms of application

Tags: c++, pointers, c++17, smart-pointers

Can anyone provide some cases in which it would be beneficial to use std::weak_ptr over std::shared_ptr? I understand the difference between them in terms of their function (std::shared_ptr keeps a reference counter and std::weak_ptr does not), and I understand the workings of smart pointers in general, I would just like to know when std::weak_ptr is preferred over std::shared_ptr, preferably with some accompanying code.

Comment: If you have a parent object that has a child object, the parent could have a shared_ptr to the child object, and the child object could have a weak_ptr to its parent object.  (If they were both shared_ptr, they'd keep each other alive.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030650/when-is-stdweak-ptr-useful

Comment: The cppreference  web resource usually has explanation **and** example code. If you just asking to start a discussion, SO has a special flag for such questions: `opinion based`.