# Usecase for weak_ptr in C++ primer 5th Edition

Tags: c++, class, c++11, c++14, weak-ptr

Hi i am reading C++ primer 5th addition and have some doubts in the section of weak_ptr. It is written that

> By using a weak_ptr, we don’t affect the lifetime of the vector to which a given StrBlob points. However, we can prevent the user from attempting to access a vector that no longer exists.

Then they have given the following code as an example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<memory>
#include<initializer_list>
using namespace std;
class StrBlobPtr;

class StrBlob {
    friend class StrBlobPtr;

public:
    typedef std::vector<std::string>::size_type size_type;
    StrBlob():data(std::make_shared<std::vector<std::string>>()){

    }
    StrBlob(std::initializer_list<std::string> il):data(make_shared<vector<std::string>>(il)){

    }
    size_type size() const {
        return data->size();
    }
    bool empty() const {
        return data->empty();
    }
    void push_back(const std::string &t){
        data->push_back(t);
    }
    std::string& front(){
        check(0,"front on empty StrBlob");
        return data->front();
    }
    std::string& front() const{
        check(0,"front on const empty StrBlob");
        return data->front();
    }
    std::string& back(){
        check(0,"back on empty StrBlob");
        return data->back();
    }
    std::string& back() const {
        check(0,"back on const empty StrBlob");
        return data->back();
    }
    void pop_back(){
        check(0,"pop_back on empty StrBlob");
        data->pop_back();
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>> data;
    void check(size_type i, const std::string &msg) const{
        if(i >= data->size()){
            throw out_of_range(msg);
        }
    }
    StrBlobPtr begin();
    StrBlobPtr end();
};


class StrBlobPtr {
    public:
        typedef std::vector<std::string>::size_type size_type;
        StrBlobPtr():curr(0){

        }
        StrBlobPtr(StrBlob &a, size_type sz = 0):wptr(a.data), curr(sz){

        }
        std::string& deref() const {
            auto p = check(curr, "dereference past end");
            return (*p)[curr];
        }
        StrBlobPtr& incr(){
            check(curr, "increment past end of StrBlobPtr");
            ++curr;
            return *this;
        }
        std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>> check(std::size_t i, const std::string &msg) const{
            auto ret = wptr.lock();
            if(!ret){
                throw std::runtime_error("unbound StrBlobPtr");
            }
            if(i>= ret->size()){
                throw std::out_of_range(msg);
            }
            return ret;
        }
    private:
        std::weak_ptr<std::vector<std::string>> wptr;
        size_type curr;
};

StrBlobPtr StrBlob::begin() {
        return StrBlobPtr(*this);
    }
StrBlobPtr StrBlob::end() {
        auto ret = StrBlobPtr(*this, data->size());
    }

int main(){
    

    return 0;
}
```

My questions are as follows:

1. How can we prevent the user from attempting to access a vector that no longer exists? I can't come up with a use case,how can we use the above quoted statement in this example?
2. How does this example shows/verifies that we can prevent the user from attempting to access a vector that no longer exists? *If this example does not shows what they have written then why is this example there in the book?*Note that i have written if.

Comment: Have you looked up what happens when you do `auto ret = wptr.lock()`?

Comment: Yes i know what happens when we write `auto ret = wptr.lock()` and i understand what is happening in this statement. Here we are checking if there are any shared_ptr pointing to the same memory to which wptr points and depending upon the result we get a nullptr or a share_ptr.

Comment: @JasonLiam followed by the line where `ret` is tested to see if the shared_ptr has already released the object `if(!ret){`  Note that the control block persists until all shared and weak pointers have been destroyed.

Comment: Well the `main()` function is empty. So the program does exactly nothing. In other words yes, it's a very bad example. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030650/when-is-stdweak-ptr-useful) will help?

Comment: @rustyx yeah i read that question also which you suggested, before posting this question. I understand why we use weak_ptr, just wanted to know if they(primer) should have given something in the main() loop also so that we can see the pointers in action. Thanks

Comment: I guess it's a question of how you define *access to the vector*.  In a multithreaded environment that `deref` function certainly won't stop the vector from going away before the string is manipulated via that potentially dangling reference.

Comment: "By using a weak_ptr, we don’t affect the lifetime of the vector to which a given StrBlob points. " I think, this sentence has to be read with special care, I think it's not precise enough. At latest in a multithreaded environment, this is often not true as soon as weak_ptr.lock() is involved.

Answer (score 1):

> *1. How can we prevent the user from attempting to access a vector that no longer exists?*

We can prevent it by exchanging a `weak_ptr` for a `shared_ptr`. [`weak_ptr::lock()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/lock) does that. It **atomically** checks if the pointed-to object still exists and increments the corresponding `shared_ptr` ref count, thus "blocking" any possible deletion from that point on.

So after this line:

```
        auto ret = wptr.lock();
```

`ret` will be a `shared_ptr` that either owns the object or doesn't, and that fact will not change for as long as `ret` exists.

Then with a simple test you can safely check if there is an object or not:

```
        if(!ret){
            /* no object anymore */
        }
```

At the end the function does `return ret;`, which returns a copy of it, thus still preventing an object from being deleted (ref count is again incremented and then decremented). So as long as you own an instance of `shared_ptr`, you can rest assured the object will continue to exist.

However, here we have a problem:

```
    std::string& deref() const {
        auto p = check(curr, "dereference past end");
        return (*p)[curr];
    }
```

This returns a reference to `std::string` inside a `vector` which, after `p` goes out of scope is held only by `weak_ptr`, i.e. a potentially dangling reference (which is no different from a dangling pointer).

> *2. How does this example shows/verifies that we can prevent the user from attempting to access a vector that no longer exists?*

Apparently it doesn't. Just ignore it.

Comment: To be safe, it should be `std::shared_ptr<std::string> deref()` with `shared_ptr` alias constructor.