# C++ set all pointers pointing to an object to null at once

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

```
while(condition){
    TConfig* curConfig = new TConfig();
    for( auto it : configMap)
    {
        itr->second = curConfig;
    }
}

if(condition)
    delete configMap[2];
    // set all elements equal to confidMap[2] to null
```

I need to make a map of pointers. Some elements in the map will be same. When I process one element I need all the same elements to be set to null. One option is to iterate over the map each time I process an element and set the elements to null. Can this be achieved in a more efficient way. Maybe by using shared Pointers.

Comment: Sounds like a case for shared_ptr and weak_ptr. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030650/when-is-stdweak-ptr-useful). Using a weak pointer you can check if the original pointer it was created from has since been deleted.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<TConfig>> configs;
std::unordered_map<int, size_t> configMap; // value is index in configs
```

Now when you want to make a new config:

```
configMap[someKey1] = configs.size(); // capture index in configs
configMap[someKey2] = configs.size();
configs.emplace_back(new TConfig());
```

That is, you add as many entries as you want to `configMap`, each having the index of a new TConfig in the `configs` vector.

Now when you want to reset one of the TConfig pointers (destroying the config object), do this:

```
configs[configMap[2]].reset(); // instead of delete configMap[2];
```

That doesn't remove `configMap[2]`, it simply resets the unique_ptr in `configs`.  So now any other entries in `configMap` which pointed to the same pointer in `configs` will now be pointing to the null `std::unique_ptr<TConfig>`.

Answer (score 1):

The map value could be a pointer to a `unique_ptr` as in the example below demonstrating the operations of the question.

Notice that while this solution makes it relatively easy to use the map, the downside is that destructing the `configMap` with its `unique_ptr` pointers gets ugly. In a full solution, the `configMap` should be an object of a class where this destruction procedure is implemented in the destructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <memory>

struct TConfig  // Just an example "config" structure
{
   int a;
   // ...
};

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<TConfig> *> configMap;

    // Create new config inside a unique_ptr
    std::unique_ptr<TConfig> *curConfig = new std::unique_ptr<TConfig>(new TConfig{42});
    
    // Assign the new config to a couple of keys
    configMap[2] = curConfig;
    configMap[3] = curConfig;
    
    // Access the config via the map
    std::cout << "configMap[3] -> " << (*configMap[3])->a << std::endl;

    // Using the unique_ptr as a bool determines if its object is defined
    std::cout << "configMap[3] present: " << ((*configMap[3])?"yes":"no") << std::endl;
    
    // Deleting the config for any key ...
    configMap[2]->reset();
    
    // ... will invalidate it for all keys:
    std::cout << "configMap[3] present: " << ((*configMap[3])?"yes":"no") << std::endl;

    // Destructing configMap is cumbersome since each unique key must
    // be destructed only once.
    // This is accomplished by making a set of keys and destructing
    // each element of that set:
    std::set<std::unique_ptr<TConfig> *> configMapDestructor;
    for(auto it = configMap.begin(); it != configMap.end(); it++)
    {
        configMapDestructor.insert(it->second);
    }
    for(auto it = configMapDestructor.begin(); it != configMapDestructor.end(); it++)
    {
        delete *it;
    }

    return 0;
}
```