# What is the use of weak_ptr in C++?

Tags: shared-ptr

I started understanding about smart pointers of C++ and I do not see any useful use of weak_ptr. Can someone let me know, what is the use of the weak_ptr in C++?

I tried to read some document related to weak_ptr but I count not understand the use of the weak_ptr.

Comment: Duplicate of [When is std::weak\_ptr useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030650/when-is-stdweak-ptr-useful) In fact the first paragraph is exactly the same other than minor word tweaks so this is very suspicious.