If unique_ptr frees its pointer when destroyed, how am I supposed to know if other pointers to the same memory are still valid?
I'm currently struggling understanding the purpose of unique_ptr.
I would like to have some kind of reference somewhere else of the content of std::unique_ptr<Component> component stored inside any instance of the Object class. Since we are using smart pointer, the raw pointer pComp should NEVER manage memory itself because the unique_ptr is the sole responsible for it, and this one of the core principle of Smart Pointers. However, what confuses me is that once we go out of scope and the destructor of unique_ptr is called, which in turn free the memory, there's no way for me to check if the memory is still valid on some other part of my code that are referencing, but not owning, to the same memory address (in this case, pComp).
I understand that using a unique_ptr is a very clear statement about the fact that Object is the owner of that memory and no one else should be responsible for it, but then what's the point of using it if the rest of my code can't check if the memory is still valid?
Why unique_ptr do not set their internal pointer to nullptr? Am I misunderstanding the use of unique_ptr? Is there a correct way to do this? If this is a case where I should use shared_ptr, why so since I want Object to be the only responsible? Thanks to everyone in advance.
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Component
{
public:
    Component() { std::cout << "Component Constructor" << std::endl; }
    ~Component() { std::cout << "Component Destructor" << std::endl; }
};

class Object
{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<Component> component;

    Object() : component(std::make_unique<Component>()) { std::cout << "Object Constructor" << std::endl; }
    ~Object() { std::cout << "Object Destructor" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Component* pComp = nullptr;
    {
        Object obj;
        pComp = obj.component.get();
    }

    if (pComp == nullptr)
        std::cout << "pComp is nullptr\n"; // This code is never reached.

    return 0;
}

EDIT: ok, I see the problem with pComp. I realized I misunderstood a basic concept. Even if the unique_ptr sets its internal pointer to nullptr, this would not automatically sets pComp to nullptr as well, therefore pComp would just become a dangling pointer since the memory it was pointing to has been freed. Thanks everyone for helping me understand this.
Still, my confusion about the use of unique_ptr persists. If the only way to have a reference that I can check for nullptr somewhere else would be this:
class Component
{
public:
    Component() { std::cout << "Component Constructor" << std::endl; }
    ~Component() { std::cout << "Component Destructor" << std::endl; }
};

class Object
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Component> component; // This is now shared_ptr

    Object() : component(std::make_shared<Component>()) { std::cout << "Object Constructor" << std::endl; }
    ~Object() { std::cout << "Object Destructor" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    std::weak_ptr<Component> pComp{}; // weak_ptr istead of raw pointer
    {
        Object obj;
        pComp = obj.component;
    }

    if (pComp.expired())
        std::cout << "pComp is expired\n";

    return 0;
}


What are the uses of unique_ptr when it comes to unique ownership? While the previous solution work because technically the only "real owner" of the memory is obj, the solution is ambiguous. shared_ptr allow the programmer to copy it and create a shared_ptr somewhere else, which imply we now have another owner somewhere else, and this is not what I want. I can't even prevent this by enforcing the use of weak_ptr. Am I still misunderstanding something? If unique_ptr imply unique ownership, but I can't have other part of the code read (only read, not own) because I can't check for nullptr, how am I supposed to use it then? Should I use it only in the scope of Object itself and not outside of it?

You shouldn't use the unique_ptr get method unless you are sure what you are doing, because it might indeed cause you to loose the "protection" of the smart pointer.

pComp is not the internal pointer inside the unique_ptr it points to the memory component pointed to at the time obj and obj.component still existed.

This is not a [mcve]

Why unique_ptr do not set their internal pointer to nullptr? I think there is some confusion that neither answer explained. Even if unique_ptr did set it's internal pointer to nullptr, that would have no effect on pComp whatsoever. These are two different pointer variables that have nothing in common besides storing the same value. Similarly, if I have int a = 1; and int b = a;, assigning b = 5; does nothing to a despite them having the same value initially.

TL;DR We use smart pointer when we don't want to handle object/memory lifetime (manual free/delete) by ourself.

What have you understood about "ownership" so far? This is key to understanding unique_ptr's WHAT (regardles of its HOW)

@PepijnKramer what I understand is that ownership is a declaration of intent and define who is responsible to manage a specific memory address.

What do you think would change if unique_ptr set its internal pointer to nullptr?

Actually, (at least) some implementations of unique_ptr do set their internal pointer to nullptr: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/unique_ptr.h#L399 -- this does not change any observed behavior though, and the compiler is allowed to optimize this away (the pointer may never have been stored to memory for example).

@user3840170 now that I've understood my trivial mistake regarding the use of pComp, that would change nothing. Setting the internal pointer to nullptr will not automatically set all other external pointers to nullptr.

https://youtu.be/JfmTagWcqoE

It appears you are conflating your confusion of unique_ptr with another confusion about object lifetime management and dangling references.

If you need to access an object owned by one object from outside, you might want to also take a look at weak_ptr : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030650/when-is-stdweak-ptr-useful

Please avoid “EDIT: DISREGARD THAT”. Try to integrate corrections into the main body of the question.

The get member is provided to be immediately passed to none-owning C-API functions; its result must not be stored for later use. That way, at every point in program there is only one owner for the allocated object, hence the name unique.

In your example, pComp has a copy of the pointer value of that stored by obj.component. When obj is destructed, copies of that pointer value become invalid. There is no way in C++ to test for invalid pointers, it is up to the programmer to ensure they are never accessed.

Why unique_ptr do not set their internal pointer to nullptr?

The unique_ptr doesn't null its underlying pointer in its destructor, because that pointer is about to cease to exist.

Is there a correct way to do this?

No, you should either extend the lifetime of obj, or take ownership of obj.component with your own unique_ptr. Only if you can't do either of those should you consider changing to shared_ptr.

So use unique_ptr instead of pointers. You will then get:
int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Component> pComp;
    {
        Object obj;
        pComp = obj.component; // compile error
    }
}

It's up to you if you want to std::move component out of object or you have to use the objects component.

then what's the point of using it if the rest of my code can't check if the memory is still valid?

RAII style automatic memory deallocation.

Why unique_ptr do not set their internal pointer to nullptr?

Why would it? It's an instruction that has to execute, that is time.

Is there a correct way to do this?

It's up to you what you define as "correct" semantics with your object. C++ is just hammer, it's up to where you hit.

where I should use shared_ptr, why so since I want Object to be the only responsible?

Sounds like no, bit I think you also want to make unique_ptr const so you can't move out of it.
class Object
{
public:
    const std::unique_ptr<Component> component;

...
    {
        Object obj;
        pComp = std::move(obj.component); // also compile error
    }

Than the way the only way will be to use obj.component to get to the component. But then, you still can use .get() and get raw pointer. It's up to the programmer to write proper code.
